# Receiving Custom Protocol Packets With Scapy and NetFilter Queue

Tags: python, networking, packet, scapy, netfilter

I am doing a project that involves shimming a packet with a custom layer containing some specific fields. I managed to do this using the guide here:

http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html

The guide is great on how to build and send packets with custom layers, but not so much on how to receive them.

I have a packet with the form:

```
IP()/CustomLayer()/ICMP()
```

And I am sending this packet to another host that will receive the packet using python's netfilter queue and scapy libraries.

My question is, how do I receive an incoming packet with custom layers in it and still have access to the fields? Trying to parse the packet with

```
IP(packet)
```

seems to not be working..
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to declare an empty packet first?

```
pkt = IP()/CustomLayer()/ICMP()
```

and then

```
pkt = IP(packet)
```

Look here and you may find the solution to your problem: [Extract Scapy Custom layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723554/extract-received-data-in-a-tcp-socket-in-python)