# Extract received data in a tcp socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, scapy, raw-sockets

I have a client sending a packet with a custom layer "Reservation" created with Scapy

**Client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
from scapy.all import *


class Reservation(Packet):
    name = "ReservationPacket"
    fields_desc=[ ShortField("id", 0),
            BitField("type",None, 0),
            X3BytesField("update", 0),
            ByteField("rssiap", 0)]


pkt = IP(len=16384, src='192.168.240.5', dst='192.168.240.198',
id=RandShort(), ttl=2)/TCP(sport=5005,
dport=5005, flags="S", window=200,
options=[('MSS', 1460), ('WScale',    2)])/Reservation(id=11)/"HELLO"

spkt = bytes(pkt)
spkt += '\x00'*20

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

s.sendto(spkt, ('192.168.240.198', 5005))

s.close()
```

The packet is correctly sent and received.

How can I access a specific field of the packet? How can I interpret the received data? I would like to use something similar to *spkt.id* in order to retrieve the value of that field. Is it possible somehow?

EDIT
I've reached this point:
I am sending a pcaket over a tcp socket. It has the following structure:

```
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4
  ihl       = None
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 16384
  id        = <RandShort>
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 2
  proto     = tcp
  chksum    = None
  src       = 192.168.240.5
  dst       = 192.168.240.1
  \options   \
###[ TCP ]###
     sport     = 5005
     dport     = 5005
     seq       = 0
     ack       = 0
     dataofs   = None
     reserved  = 0
     flags     = S
     window    = 200
     chksum    = None
     urgptr    = 0
     options   = [('MSS', 1460), ('WScale', 2)]
###[ ReservationPacket ]###
     id        = 9
     type      = None
     update    = 0x0
     rssiap    = 0 
###[ Raw ]###
      load      = 'PROVA'
```

Where **ReservationPacket** is a custom layer.
The packet is received and with

```
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
          print "received data:", data
          by = str.encode(data)             
          pkt_hex = by.encode('hex')
          hexdump(by)
          container = IP(data)
          container.show()
```

I fill the container packet, which is defined as

```
container = IP()/TCP()/Reservation()
```

The output of

```
container.show()
```

is

```
###[ IP ]###
version   = 4L
ihl       = 5L
tos       = 0x0
len       = 16384
id        = 56856
flags     = 
frag      = 0L
ttl       = 2
proto     = tcp
chksum    = 0x3987
src       = 192.168.240.5
dst       = 192.168.240.1
\options   \
###[ TCP ]###
 sport     = 5005
 dport     = 5005
 seq       = 0
 ack       = 0
 dataofs   = 7L
 reserved  = 0L
 flags     = S
 window    = 200
 chksum    = 0xd962
 urgptr    = 0
 options   = [('MSS', 1460), ('WScale', 2), ('EOL', None)]
###[ Raw ]###
    load      = '\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x00PROVA'
```

Apparently the Reservation layer is not recognized and interpreted as RAW. How can I build the same packet as the one transmitted?

Comment: Are you using scapy v2.x or v3.x?

Comment: Scapy 2.3.1 and Python 2.7

Comment: You are not supposed to use `bytes` in scapy v2.x. Normally, you would use smth. like pkt[Reservation].id to access field value, but I did not check your code in full as I am on scapy v3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `s=str(packet)` to serialize a packet in scapy 2 and `packet=Layer(s)` to force deserialization of a bytestream as `Layer`.

In your case:

```
rdata = sock.recv(8192)
layer = Reservation(rdata)
layer.show()
print layer.id
```

Note that you can also bind your layer for scapys autodissect/payload guessing with `bind_layers()` to make it work with `sniff()` or dissection of tcp/Reservation bytestreams (tcp packet with reservation payload). The following line binds TCP.dport=5005 to Reservation.

```
bind_layers(TCP, Reservation, dport=5005)
```

**update:** specific answer to your question.

You do not have to care about the IP/TCP layer as this is all handled within the socket. The data that is received by `socket.recv` is the payload to `TCP` therefore all you have to do is to force scapy to deserialize the received `data` as `Reservation`.

TCP Socket:

```
data=[]
while True:
    chunk = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not chunk: 
        break
    print "received data:", chunk
    data.append(chunk)
layer = Reservation(''.join(data))
layer.show()
print layer.id
```

Additionally, you can instruct scapy to try to auto-dissect your layer based on a simple rule e.g. `TCP.dport==5005` with a call to `bind_layers()`. This way it will also work with `sniff` or whenever you receive the full `IP/TCP/Reservation/Raw` bytestream.

Raw Socket:

```
bind_layers(TCP, Reservation, dport=5005) # bind Reservation as nextlayer to TCP.dport=5005
# ...
data, peer = s.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
print "received data:", peer, repr(data)
layer = IP(data)                # dissection automagic based on rules registered with bind_layers
layer.show()
print layer[Reservation].id
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you have a look here of what I tried to do?
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744890/receive-scapy-packet-with-custom-layer-in-python)

Comment: please merge your duplicate question.

Comment: using bind_layers() as you suggested it's working fine! Thank you very much.

Comment: if you merge your question you'll get a complete answer with an example for a) bind_layers and b) forced dissection.

Comment: Please can you share the link / solution. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: added a `raw_socket` example with `bind_layers` if that was what you're asking for.